# NSAttributedString html issue

Tags: html, uitextview, nsattributedstring

When we are using nsattributedstring to render html we are seeing unnecessary gaps.
I tried using display mode inline tag. I have tried removing the '\n'. Many such things but html is rendering spaces for uitextview.
https://hub.mangoapps.com/msc/NDY5MTEyXzM2MzM5NTk

Options to remove this unnecessary spacing
I also followed this https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-remove-extra-padding-when-converting-html-to-nsattributedstring/

Comment: Could you share maybe the original HTML string to help reproduce exactly?

Comment: I don't have that html. But Here is similar html
<head><meta name='color-scheme' content='light dark'/></head><style>div.a {font-family: -apple-system ;font-size: 16px; } .light-grey { color:grey; } .strike-out-text { text-decoration: line-through; } </style><div "vertical-align: top;" class="a"><class="a">Hi this is new for meHH
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Hi ahello how r u  n d i google
            <br>
        </li>
        <li>JHj</li>
    </ul>
</div></div>
https://hub.mangoapps.com/msc/NTUyNTExXzQxMzM0NDM
Here I have used UITextView